# java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: At least one parameter to the current statement is uninitialized

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, derby

I'm trying to get a SUM of Integer values from database (in my project called "vsota") and displaying it in a `JLabel` (in my project called "vpd"). And the code provided doesn't work. Here is the exception :

> Error: *java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: At least one parameter to the current statement is uninitialized.*

```
try {
    stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    String sql = "SELECT SUM(vsota) FROM Vse WHERE vsota = ?";
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    rs.next();
    int stevilo = rs.getInt("vsota");
    String vsota = Integer.toString(stevilo);

    vpd.setText(vsota);

} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ZačetniObrazec.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: [Java != JavaScript](http://javascriptisnotjava.com)

Comment: Why do you do the sum only for a specific "vsota" value ?

Answer (score 1):

> Error: java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: At least one parameter to the current statement is uninitialized.

Your `String` is using parameters `vsota = ?` so you need to use a `PreparedStatement` instead of a `Statement` to be able to define a value to it.

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

try{
    ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setInt(1, vSotaValue); //parameters are 1-based

    rs = ps.execute();
} finally {
    if(rs != null) try{rs.close();} catch(SQLException e){}
    if(ps != null) try{ps.close();} catch(SQLException e){}
}
```